# Rmarkdown : can we merge two cells with kableExtra?

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

Is there a way to merge two cells with `kableExtra` when knitting from `Rmarkdown` to HTML?

```
bbb = 5
aaa = data.frame(matrix(c(1,2,3,4, paste(bbb),""), nrow = 2, byrow = T))
aaa
```

I want the value `bbb` (the value of the merged cells varies) to appear in the middle of the last two columns when applying `kable(aaa) %>% kableExtra(...)`

```
> aaa
  X1 X2 X3
1  1  2  3
2  4  5
```

Any suggestion ? Thanks :-)

Comment: As far as I can tell, this functionality doesn't exist in the `kableExtra` package. It has `collapse_rows()`, which basically does what you want in the other direction, i.e. merges cells in one column spanning multiple rows. Maybe you could adapt its code for your purposes.

Comment: You can merge the columns before making the table?

Comment: How can i merge the column before applying `kable`?

Comment: @duckymar I do not know enough HTML to adapt the function `collapse_rows`.
But it's a good suggestion

Comment: @FloraGrappelli I could not get it work but you might check out the flextable pacakge (https://davidgohel.github.io/flextable/index.html). According to the documention you can merge cells and do other things similar to MS Excel.

Comment: @EdgarZamora Thansk for the suggestion. `flextable` allows the cell merging but I am using it in a loop (or with `lapply`). And it is not working in this case !